# how to find linux at job status

Tags: linux, at

Im using

```
echo "<some command> | at -q <queuename> now
```

to create a queue of jobs.

I can use atq command to get list of jobs.

I cant seem to find any command or swtich which can show me status of the job : like say running, queued, done, etc

Comment: to downvoter can you plz help me understand why is my qs downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual of at :

```
The special queue "=" is reserved for jobs which are currently running.
```

So if the job is in this queue it means that it's currently running.

For example

```
[root@test ~]# atq
8   Thu Oct 22 00:32:00 2015 a root
9   Wed Oct 21 23:38:00 2015 a root
10  Wed Oct 21 23:35:00 2015 = root
```

In that case the job number 10 is running. Other jobs are in queue "a".
When the job is done, it just disappears from the queue.